# How to manually refresh a Snowflake Marketplace listing?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a data listing in the Snowflake Marketplace being Auto-Fulfilled to other regions. Currently, my listing is set to refresh on a weekly basis. But sometimes I need to do a refresh in the middle of the week.

My current approach is to: change the schedule to be daily, wait for the refresh, and then set as weekly again.

How can I avoid having to do all that by doing a manual refresh?

Additionally, the underlying data usually only changes once a week. If I set up the schedule as daily, will I get charged every day or just when the data actually changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you can't manually refresh a listing and/or schedule a refresh to happen at a specific time. My understanding is that the schedule starts at the point when the Customer accepts the listing - so if the schedule is daily and the customer accepts the listing at 9am, it will refresh at (approximately) 9am every day.

- I would say this a major limitation with this feature at the moment

The underlying refresh mechanism is standard Snowflake replication - which can be either incremental or full refresh, depending on how exactly your source data objects are configured. So, if it can, Snowflake will do an incremental refresh.

However, for example, if the source objects are dynamic tables with masking policies, Snowflake will always do a full refresh. This is something that, I believe, Snowflake are looking to address in a future release

*This information is based on my knowledge of Private Listings. I believe it is also applicable to Marketplace listings but I'm happy for someone else, with more experience of Marketplace, to prove me wrong

Comment: Thanks for sharing your perspective.
re: full refresh vs incremental
In my case, the listing itself is comprised of 3 secure views that reference 3 underlying tables using a filter. The 3 underlying tables are only updated once a week. Do you think in this case SF would charge for daily fulfilling, even if the tables are the same most of the time?

Comment: I would expect it to do incremental refreshes - but you can always check by looking at SNOWFLAKE.DATA_SHARING_USAGE.LISTING_AUTO_FULFILLMENT_REFRESH_DAILY and see if the bytes_transferred reflect a full or incremental refresh

Comment: Cool, I'll monitor this view in the following days

Comment: It does an incremental refresh in my case